# MVC Razor brackets inside code block

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I'm having issues do linq queries inside of a code block.

```
@{
  var foo = @Model.Things.Select((value, index) => new { value, index });
}
```

The problem is the new{}, it sees the second bracket as closing the entire code block. Any way to escape it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Remove the `@` from `Model`:

```
@{
  var foo = Model.Things.Select((value, index) => new { value, index });
}
```

Comment: Strangely, in MVC4 if you do this in a code block, the ampersand in front of the model won't be flagged as an error, but other errors will be returned. MVC3 did not have a problem with the @Model directive inside a code block for me.

Answer (score 5):

Please try

```
@{
 var foo = Model.Things.Select((value, index) => new { value, index });
}
```